# mergerfs or similar on a Mac for combining multiple drives?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, filesystem

I want to setup an old Mac Pro as a media server. In my recent setup, I use mergerfs to combine multiple drives into one which I can share. I would like to do the same on the Mac. I have seen, that mergerfs does not support the Mac, and that mhddfs is not maintained anymore.

Is there an alternative for macOS?

Answer (score 1):

The `README.md` file for the mergefs project on [GitHub](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs) answers this for you...

> mergerfs is a union filesystem geared towards simplifying storage and management of files across numerous commodity storage devices. It is similar to mhddfs, **unionfs**, and aufs.

<sup>**Emphasis Mine**</sup>

Unionfs is a FUSE project (available on [GitHub](https://github.com/rpodgorny/unionfs-fuse)) that claims to have Mac support.  There hasn’t been much development in the last few years so, how well it works with your version of macOS will be up in the air.

That said, it’s probably a better idea to just standardize the formats over those multiple drives to reduce complexity and ensure reliability.  If these drives are running in different machines with different OSes, [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) might be the direction you want to go.